# How can i extract a file in ubuntu?

Tags: extract

I have a zip file ( which is named ccnx-0.7.0.tar.gzip) and a related sha file( which is named ccnx-0.7.0.tar.gz.SHA1). i downloaded them from "https://www.ccnx.org/software-archives/#"  how can i extract this file in ubuntu?

thanks in advanced

Comment: and if you want to install them follow [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it by running

```
tar -xvzf ccnx-0.7.0.tar.gzip
```

in your terminal.

You will find the output in your current directory.

You can type

```
man tar
```

for more options and infos about tar